# Java Calendar clear() changes DST

Tags: java, datetime, calendar, dst, java.util.calendar

First, I want to state that I know the Java Calendar class is being supplanted by other libraries that are arguably better. Perhaps I've stumbled upon one of the reasons Calendar has fallen out of favor.

I ran into frustrating behavior in Calendar as it regards to the overlapping hour at the end of daylight savings time.

```
public void annoying_issue()
{
    Calendar midnightPDT = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("US/Pacific"));
    midnightPDT.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2021);
    midnightPDT.set(Calendar.MONTH, 10);
    midnightPDT.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 7);
    midnightPDT.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    midnightPDT.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    midnightPDT.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    midnightPDT.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

    Calendar oneAMPDT = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("US/Pacific"));
    oneAMPDT.setTimeInMillis(midnightPDT.getTimeInMillis() + (60*60*1000));//this is the easiest way I've found to get to the first 1am hour at DST overlap

    System.out.println(new Date(midnightPDT.getTimeInMillis()));//prints the expected "Sun Nov 7 00:00:00 PDT 2021" 
    System.out.println(new Date(oneAMPDT.getTimeInMillis()));//prints "Sun Nov 7 01:00:00 PDT 2021" also expected

    oneAMPDT.clear(Calendar.MINUTE);//minute is already 0 so no change should occur... RIGHT!? 
    
    //WRONG!!!!
    //The time is now in PST! The millisecond value has increased by 3600000, too!!
    System.out.println(new Date(oneAMPDT.getTimeInMillis()));//prints "Sun Nov 7 01:00:00 PST 2021"
}
```

Following along with the comments you'll see that clearing the MINUTE field in the calendar actually moved it up an hour! The HECK!?

This also occurs when I use `oneAMPDT.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0)`

Is this expected behavior? Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: `clear` sets a field to undefined, not zero, although I would expect the default value for MINUTE to be zero anyway.

Comment: It is actual reality. The local time has somewhere a gap of an hour, or repeats an hour. Exact time should fall back on UTC. Try a day later.

Comment: I have reproduced. Also with `oneAMPDT.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);` instead, same result.

Comment: I spent an hour looking at the source of Calendar and GregorianCalendar, and I still can’t figure out why this happens.  I do know that clear(MINUTE) changes the DST_OFFSET field to zero, but I can’t figure out why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Avoid legacy date-time classes; convert if needed

As you noted, `Calendar` was supplanted years ago by the *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310 (unanimously adopted). And as you note there are *many* reasons to avoid using `Calendar` & `Date` etc.

If you must have a `Calendar` object to interoperate with old code not yet updated to *java.time*, convert after doing your work in *java.time*.

## *java.time*

Specify your desired time zone. Note that `US/Pacific` is merely an alias for the actual time zone, `America/Los_Angeles`.

```
ZoneId zLosAngeles = ZoneId.of( "America/Los_Angeles" ) ;
```

Specify your desired moment.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 2021 , Month.NOVEMBER , 7 ) ;
```

In your code, you seem to assume the first moment of the day occurs at 00:00. That is not always the case. Some dates in some time zones may start at another time. So let *java.time* determine the first moment of the day.

```
ZonedDateTime firstMomentOfThe7thInLosAngeles = ld.atStartOfDay( zLosAngeles ) ;
```

> firstMomentOfThe7thInLosAngeles.toString(): 2021-11-07T00:00-07:00[America/Los_Angeles]

But then you jumped to another moment, to 1 AM.

```
ZonedDateTime oneAmOnThe7thLosAngeles = firstMomentOfThe7thInLosAngeles.with( LocalTime.of( 1 , 0 ) ) ;
```

> oneAmOnThe7thLosAngeles.toString(): 2021-11-07T01:00-07:00[America/Los_Angeles]

That time-of-day may or may not exist on that date in that zone. The `ZonedDateTime` class will adjust if need be.

You used the name `midnightPDT` for a variable. I suggest avoiding the term `midnight` as its use confuses date-time handling with out a precise definition. I recommend using the term "first moment of the day" if that is what you mean.

You extract a count of milliseconds since the epoch reference of first moment of 1970 as seen in UTC, 1970-01-01T00:00Z.

```
Instant firstMomentOfThe7thInLosAngelesAsSeenInUtc = firstMomentOfThe7thInLosAngeles.toInstant() ;
long millisSinceEpoch_FirstMomentOf7thLosAngeles = firstMomentOfThe7thInLosAngelesAsSeenInUtc.toEpochMilli() ;
```

> firstMomentOfThe7thInLosAngelesAsSeenInUtc.toString(): 2021-11-07T07:00:00Z
>
> millisSinceEpoch_FirstMomentOf7thLosAngeles = 1636268400000

And you do the same for our 1 AM moment.

```
Instant oneAmOnThe7thLosAngelesAsSeenInUtc = oneAmOnThe7thLosAngeles.toInstant() ;
long millisSinceEpoch_OneAmOn7thLosAngeles = oneAmOnThe7thLosAngelesAsSeenInUtc.toEpochMilli() ;
```

> oneAmOnThe7thLosAngelesAsSeenInUtc.toString(): 2021-11-07T08:00:00Z
>
> millisSinceEpoch_OneAmOn7thLosAngeles = 1636272000000

We should see a difference of one hour. An hour = 3,600,000 = 60 * 60 * 1,000.

```
long diff = ( millisSinceEpoch_OneAmOn7thLosAngeles - millisSinceEpoch_FirstMomentOf7thLosAngeles );  // 3,600,000 = 60 * 60 * 1,000.
```

> diff = 3600000

### Cutover

Then you go on to mention the [Daylight Saving Time (DST)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time) cutover. The cutover for DST in the United States on that date was 2 AM, not 1 AM. At the moment of 2 AM arriving, the clocks swung back to 1 AM, for a second 1:00-2:00 AM hour.

To get to that point of cutover, let's add an hour.

```
ZonedDateTime cutover_Addition = oneAmOnThe7thLosAngeles.plusHours( 1 );
```

> cutover_Addition = 2021-11-07T01:00-08:00[America/Los_Angeles]

Notice that the time-of-day shows the same (1 AM), but the offset-from-UTC has changed from being 7 hours behind UTC to now 8 hours behind UTC. There lies the hour difference you seek.

Let's get the count of milliseconds since epoch for this third moment. Before we had first moment of the day (00:00), then the first occurring 1 AM, and now we have the second occurring 1 AM on this “Fall-Back” date of November 7, 2021.

```
long millisSinceEpoch_Cutover = cutover_Addition.toInstant().toEpochMilli();
```

> 1636275600000
>
> Duration.between( firstMomentOfThe7thInLosAngelesAsSeenInUtc , cutover_Addition.toInstant() ) = PT2H
>
> Duration.between( oneAmOnThe7thLosAngelesAsSeenInUtc , cutover_Addition.toInstant() ) = PT1H

The `ZonedDateTime` class does offer a pair of methods of use at these moments of cutover: `withEarlierOffsetAtOverlap` and `withLaterOffsetAtOverlap`.

```java
ZonedDateTime cutover_OverlapEarlier =
        cutover_Addition
                .withEarlierOffsetAtOverlap();
ZonedDateTime cutover_OverlapLater =
        cutover_Addition
                .withLaterOffsetAtOverlap();
```

> cutover_OverlapEarlier = 2021-11-07T01:00-07:00[America/Los_Angeles]
>
> cutover_OverlapLater = 2021-11-07T01:00-08:00[America/Los_Angeles]

### `Calendar`

If you really need a `Calendar` object, just convert.

```
Calendar x = GregorianCalendar.from( firstMomentOfThe7thInLosAngeles ) ;
Calendar y = GregorianCalendar.from( oneAmOnThe7thLosAngeles ) ;
Calendar z = GregorianCalendar.from( cutover_Addition );
```

If you goal is simply struggling with understanding `Calendar` class behavior, I suggest you stop the masochism. There is no point. Sun, Oracle, and the JCP community [all gave up](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/results?id=4160) on those terrible legacy date-time classes. I suggest you do the same.

### Example code

Pulling together all that code above.

```java
ZoneId zLosAngeles = ZoneId.of( "America/Los_Angeles" );

LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 2021 , Month.NOVEMBER , 7 );

ZonedDateTime firstMomentOfThe7thInLosAngeles = ld.atStartOfDay( zLosAngeles );
ZonedDateTime oneAmOnThe7thLosAngeles = firstMomentOfThe7thInLosAngeles.with( LocalTime.of( 1 , 0 ) );

Instant firstMomentOfThe7thInLosAngelesAsSeenInUtc = firstMomentOfThe7thInLosAngeles.toInstant();
long millisSinceEpoch_FirstMomentOf7thLosAngeles = firstMomentOfThe7thInLosAngelesAsSeenInUtc.toEpochMilli();

Instant oneAmOnThe7thLosAngelesAsSeenInUtc = oneAmOnThe7thLosAngeles.toInstant();
long millisSinceEpoch_OneAmOn7thLosAngeles = oneAmOnThe7thLosAngelesAsSeenInUtc.toEpochMilli();

long diff = ( millisSinceEpoch_OneAmOn7thLosAngeles - millisSinceEpoch_FirstMomentOf7thLosAngeles );  // 3,600,000 = 60 * 60 * 1,000.

ZonedDateTime cutover_Addition = oneAmOnThe7thLosAngeles.plusHours( 1 );
long millisSinceEpoch_Cutover = cutover_Addition.toInstant().toEpochMilli();
ZonedDateTime cutover_OverlapEarlier =
        cutover_Addition
                .withEarlierOffsetAtOverlap();
ZonedDateTime cutover_OverlapLater =
        cutover_Addition
                .withLaterOffsetAtOverlap();
```

Convert to legacy classes, if need be.

```java
Calendar x = GregorianCalendar.from( firstMomentOfThe7thInLosAngeles );
Calendar y = GregorianCalendar.from( oneAmOnThe7thLosAngeles );
Calendar z = GregorianCalendar.from( cutover_Addition );
```

Dump to console.

```java
System.out.println( "firstMomentOfThe7thInLosAngeles = " + firstMomentOfThe7thInLosAngeles );
System.out.println( "oneAmOnThe7thLosAngeles = " + oneAmOnThe7thLosAngeles );

System.out.println( "firstMomentOfThe7thInLosAngelesAsSeenInUtc = " + firstMomentOfThe7thInLosAngelesAsSeenInUtc );
System.out.println( "millisSinceEpoch_FirstMomentOf7thLosAngeles = " + millisSinceEpoch_FirstMomentOf7thLosAngeles );

System.out.println( "oneAmOnThe7thLosAngelesAsSeenInUtc = " + oneAmOnThe7thLosAngelesAsSeenInUtc );
System.out.println( "millisSinceEpoch_OneAmOn7thLosAngeles = " + millisSinceEpoch_OneAmOn7thLosAngeles );

System.out.println( "diff = " + diff );

System.out.println( "x = " + x );
System.out.println( "y = " + y );
System.out.println( "z = " + z );

System.out.println( "cutover_Addition = " + cutover_Addition );
System.out.println( "millisSinceEpoch_Cutover = " + millisSinceEpoch_Cutover );
System.out.println( "Duration.between( firstMomentOfThe7thInLosAngelesAsSeenInUtc , cutover_Addition.toInstant() ) = " + Duration.between( firstMomentOfThe7thInLosAngelesAsSeenInUtc , cutover_Addition.toInstant() ) );
System.out.println( "Duration.between( oneAmOnThe7thLosAngelesAsSeenInUtc , cutover_Addition.toInstant() ) = " + Duration.between( oneAmOnThe7thLosAngelesAsSeenInUtc , cutover_Addition.toInstant() ) );
System.out.println( "cutover_OverlapEarlier = " + cutover_OverlapEarlier );
System.out.println( "cutover_OverlapLater = " + cutover_OverlapLater );
```

When run.

```
firstMomentOfThe7thInLosAngeles = 2021-11-07T00:00-07:00[America/Los_Angeles]
oneAmOnThe7thLosAngeles = 2021-11-07T01:00-07:00[America/Los_Angeles]
firstMomentOfThe7thInLosAngelesAsSeenInUtc = 2021-11-07T07:00:00Z
millisSinceEpoch_FirstMomentOf7thLosAngeles = 1636268400000
oneAmOnThe7thLosAngelesAsSeenInUtc = 2021-11-07T08:00:00Z
millisSinceEpoch_OneAmOn7thLosAngeles = 1636272000000
diff = 3600000
x = java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=1636268400000,areFieldsSet=true,areAllFieldsSet=true,lenient=true,zone=sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="America/Los_Angeles",offset=-28800000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,transitions=185,lastRule=java.util.SimpleTimeZone[id=America/Los_Angeles,offset=-28800000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,startYear=0,startMode=3,startMonth=2,startDay=8,startDayOfWeek=1,startTime=7200000,startTimeMode=0,endMode=3,endMonth=10,endDay=1,endDayOfWeek=1,endTime=7200000,endTimeMode=0]],firstDayOfWeek=2,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=4,ERA=1,YEAR=2021,MONTH=10,WEEK_OF_YEAR=44,WEEK_OF_MONTH=1,DAY_OF_MONTH=7,DAY_OF_YEAR=311,DAY_OF_WEEK=1,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=1,AM_PM=0,HOUR=0,HOUR_OF_DAY=0,MINUTE=0,SECOND=0,MILLISECOND=0,ZONE_OFFSET=-28800000,DST_OFFSET=3600000]
y = java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=1636272000000,areFieldsSet=true,areAllFieldsSet=true,lenient=true,zone=sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="America/Los_Angeles",offset=-28800000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,transitions=185,lastRule=java.util.SimpleTimeZone[id=America/Los_Angeles,offset=-28800000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,startYear=0,startMode=3,startMonth=2,startDay=8,startDayOfWeek=1,startTime=7200000,startTimeMode=0,endMode=3,endMonth=10,endDay=1,endDayOfWeek=1,endTime=7200000,endTimeMode=0]],firstDayOfWeek=2,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=4,ERA=1,YEAR=2021,MONTH=10,WEEK_OF_YEAR=44,WEEK_OF_MONTH=1,DAY_OF_MONTH=7,DAY_OF_YEAR=311,DAY_OF_WEEK=1,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=1,AM_PM=0,HOUR=1,HOUR_OF_DAY=1,MINUTE=0,SECOND=0,MILLISECOND=0,ZONE_OFFSET=-28800000,DST_OFFSET=3600000]
z = java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=1636275600000,areFieldsSet=true,areAllFieldsSet=true,lenient=true,zone=sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="America/Los_Angeles",offset=-28800000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,transitions=185,lastRule=java.util.SimpleTimeZone[id=America/Los_Angeles,offset=-28800000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,startYear=0,startMode=3,startMonth=2,startDay=8,startDayOfWeek=1,startTime=7200000,startTimeMode=0,endMode=3,endMonth=10,endDay=1,endDayOfWeek=1,endTime=7200000,endTimeMode=0]],firstDayOfWeek=2,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=4,ERA=1,YEAR=2021,MONTH=10,WEEK_OF_YEAR=44,WEEK_OF_MONTH=1,DAY_OF_MONTH=7,DAY_OF_YEAR=311,DAY_OF_WEEK=1,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=1,AM_PM=0,HOUR=1,HOUR_OF_DAY=1,MINUTE=0,SECOND=0,MILLISECOND=0,ZONE_OFFSET=-28800000,DST_OFFSET=0]
cutover_Addition = 2021-11-07T01:00-08:00[America/Los_Angeles]
millisSinceEpoch_Cutover = 1636275600000
Duration.between( firstMomentOfThe7thInLosAngelesAsSeenInUtc , cutover_Addition.toInstant() ) = PT2H
Duration.between( oneAmOnThe7thLosAngelesAsSeenInUtc , cutover_Addition.toInstant() ) = PT1H
cutover_OverlapEarlier = 2021-11-07T01:00-07:00[America/Los_Angeles]
cutover_OverlapLater = 2021-11-07T01:00-08:00[America/Los_Angeles]
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! Helpful confirmation that we need to convert to the JSR 310 spec. My favorite part was 'I suggest you stop the masochism. There is no point.' Well stated, point taken!

For anyone who can't make the switch, check out Ole's answer below.

Answer (score 2):

### java.time

*Is this expected behavior?* No. I consider it a bug.

*Is there a way to prevent this?* Yes, the way you already mentioned or at least implied: use `ZonedDateTime` instead of `Calendar`. Basil Bourque has said it already. As a modest supplement I wanted to show the full round-trip from `Calendar` to `ZonedDateTime`, setting minute to 0 and converting back to `Calendar`. In case you need this for interoperability with your legacy code.

```
    GregorianCalendar oneAmPdt = new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getTimeZone(ZoneId.of("America/Los_Angeles")));
    oneAmPdt.clear();
    oneAmPdt.set(2021, Calendar.NOVEMBER, 7, 0, 0);
    oneAmPdt.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 1);
    System.out.println(oneAmPdt.getTime());

    ZonedDateTime zdt = oneAmPdt.toZonedDateTime();

    // Minute is already 0 so no change should occur... RIGHT!?
    zdt = zdt.withMinute(0);

    oneAmPdt = GregorianCalendar.from(zdt);

    System.out.println(oneAmPdt.getTime());
```

Output:

> ```
> Sun Nov 07 01:00:00 PDT 2021
> Sun Nov 07 01:00:00 PDT 2021
> ```

But I used `GregorianCalendar`, not `Calendar`? So did you. `GregorianCalendar` is the subclass of `Calendar` that you got from `Calendar.getIntance()`. In some environments you would have got a different subclass reflecting the calendar system in use there, and your initial calls to `set` would not have given you your expected result. You *want* a `GregorianCalendar` in this case (if you cannot have a `ZonedDateTime` from the outset).

When modifying our old code I would likely do it in the above way even if it wasn’t for circumventing a bug in the old `Calendar` or `GregorianCalendar` class. It’s one small step in a long-running transition to java.time.